# Beginner to complex integration

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Unfortunately I missed one a week of lectures last week due to a family bereavement and my lecturer doesn't put up her notes (I put a request online if someone could share their notes with me but no one will). I missed quiet an important portion of complex integration. I have searched online for videos or examples but just don't understand whats happening with it. I've attempted a question but don't think I've done it correctly any advice would be brilliant.

Evaluate $$\ \int_C (z^2-z+2)\;dz $$
if C is the upper half of the unit circle (in a counter clockwise direction)

$$\ \int_{-1}^1 (z^2-z+2)\;dz = \left[\frac {z^3} {3}-\frac {z^2}{2}+2z\right]_{-1}^1 $$

$$\ \left[\frac {1} {3}-\frac {1}{2}+2\right] - \left[-\frac {1} {3}-\frac {1}{2}-2\right]$$
$$\ =\frac {14} {3} $$

Do I need to use cos and sin or am I right?
Thanks

Comment: Is $C$ a closed path?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOFdojRxaSE&list=PLBY4G2o7DhF0TSossUvJ-CTKSLfOhQgb6&index=19 might be helpful. I'm not sure exactly where you are in the course....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your description of the path of integration $C$ is right (just an arc, not a closed semicircular loop), then you need to parameterize the path. For example, you could take $z=z(t)=e^{it}$ with $t\in [0,\pi]$. The idea is that as $t$ ranges from $0$ to $\pi$, the point $z=e^{it}$ travels along the upper semicircle from $z=e^{0}=1$ to $z=e^{i\pi}=-1$.

Then you would note that $z^2=(e^{it})^2=e^{2it}$ and $dz = \frac{dz}{dt}\;dt=ie^{it}\;dt$, and so write

$$\int_C(z^2-z+2)\;dz = \int_0^{\pi}(\underbrace{e^{2it}-e^{it}+2}_{z^2-z+2})\underbrace{ie^{it}\; dt}_{dz}$$
Simplifying the integrand, 
$$=\int_0^{\pi}(ie^{3it}-ie^{2it}+2ie^{it})\; dt$$
$$=\left[\frac{e^{3it}}{3}-\frac{e^{2it}}{2}+2e^{it}\right]_0^{\pi}$$
$$=\left(-\frac13-\frac12-2\right)-\left(\frac13-\frac12+2\right)$$
$$=-\frac{14}{3}$$

Your solution has two problems: (1) you integrated in the wrong direction, and (2) you didn't parameterize the path correctly (you really used the line segment from $-1$ to $1$). Except for a sign change due to the wrong orientation, your answer matches mine because the integrand is holomorphic so the result of the integral is independent of the path. But even though the answer is (nearly) correct, the technique is wrong as I described.

Comment: thanks so much for your explanation it really clears up what I was confused about. How would this be different if it was a closed path? would I find the integral of the line from -1 to 1 and add it?

Comment: Exactly right. You will find that the result in that case is zero for your integrand. Same for any integrand which is holomorphic on the enclosed region. The reason is exactly independence of path together with the fact that integrating in the reverse direction produces the opposite value (a closed loop can be thought of as going from a point $A$ to a point $B$, then back again along another path). $\oint_Cf =0$ if $f$ is holomorphic inside of the closed curve $C$ (I'm omitting some technicalities).